# Error in sign up and in A3M

Tags: codeigniter-a3m

I install A3M Codeigniter library and there is and error when i try to sign in or sign up it returns me to the same page without posting posting, when sign up with facebook for example it back to page "Confirm your account information" and still return to this page when i click a submit button called "Complete".

- Database data is right
- I give a cache folder a 777 permissions
- .htaccess and config url is right
- I add the facebook and twitter appID and secretAppID

What is the reason of this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**I think the .htaccess file must be like this:**

`RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]`